# Setting button class back to initial after pressing next button

Tags: javascript

```js
const btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let questionTag = document.getElementById("question");
let answerTag = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
const nxt_question_btn = document.getElementById("next");
const end_quiz_btn = document.getElementById("end");

btn_start.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
nxt_question_btn.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
let currentQuestionIndex = 0;

let myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What's 2+2?",
        answers: [
            { text: "4", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
            { text: "1", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 10+10?",
        answers: [
            { text: "20", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "18", correct: false },
            { text: "0", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 30+30?",
        answers: [
            { text: "60", correct: true },
            { text: "24", correct: false },
            { text: "100", correct: false },
            { text: "50", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 10+30?",
        answers: [
            { text: "40", correct: true },
            { text: "44", correct: false },
            { text: "70", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
        ],
    },
];
function startQuiz() {
    container.style.visibility = "visible";
    btn_start.style.visibility = "hidden";
    end.style.visibility = "hidden";
    showQuestion(myQuestions[0]);
}
function showQuestion(questionAndAnswers) {
    const shuffledAnswers = _.shuffle(questionAndAnswers.answers);
    questionTag.innerText = questionAndAnswers.question;
    shuffledAnswers.forEach(({ text, correct }, i) => {
        answerTag[i].innerText = text;
        answerTag[i].dataset.correct = correct;
    });
}
document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach((answer) => {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target.dataset) {
            answer.style.border = "1px solid black";
        }
    });
});
function nextQuestion() {
    
    const nextIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
    if (nextIndex <= myQuestions.length - 1) {
        showQuestion(myQuestions[nextIndex]);
        currentQuestionIndex = nextIndex;
    } else {
        end.style.visibility = "visible";
        nxt_question_btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
    <button id="start" type="button">Start quiz</button>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Quiz</h2>
        <div class="time">
            <span>Time left:</span>
            <p id="time"> 30</p>
        </div>
        <h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
        </div>
        <button id="next" class="btns">Next Question</button>
        <button id="end" class="btns">End Quiz</button>
    </div>
```

In my Javascript quiz game, when an answer is selected, we load up another question with other answers but the problem that occurs is the selected answers get a black border but when the next question is loaded up, the border stays. How do I make it go back to normal when the next question is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `border: initial` to revert is back to default.

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial (or default) value of a property to an element. It can be applied to any CSS property. This includes the CSS shorthand all, with which initial can be used to restore all CSS properties to their initial state.

In your code, you could use:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.border = "1px solid black";
    buttons.forEach(each => {
      if (each != button) each.style.border = "initial"
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
<button id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
<button id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
<button id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
```

Or if the style of border you doesn't satisfy with, you could define a new class and use `toggle` to add / remove the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

*Also, note that your code is currently displaying `reference error`

Answer (score 0):

In your "next question" function, set the button's style properties to none. Then put a setTimeout function where you set the same element's style property to '' (empty string). This should reset it.

```js
const btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let questionTag = document.getElementById("question");
let answerTag = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
const nxt_question_btn = document.getElementById("next");
const end_quiz_btn = document.getElementById("end");

btn_start.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);
nxt_question_btn.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);
let currentQuestionIndex = 0;

let myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What's 2+2?",
        answers: [
            { text: "4", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
            { text: "1", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 10+10?",
        answers: [
            { text: "20", correct: true },
            { text: "2", correct: false },
            { text: "18", correct: false },
            { text: "0", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 30+30?",
        answers: [
            { text: "60", correct: true },
            { text: "24", correct: false },
            { text: "100", correct: false },
            { text: "50", correct: false },
        ],
    },
    {
        question: "What's 10+30?",
        answers: [
            { text: "40", correct: true },
            { text: "44", correct: false },
            { text: "70", correct: false },
            { text: "10", correct: false },
        ],
    },
];
function startQuiz() {
    container.style.visibility = "visible";
    btn_start.style.visibility = "hidden";
    end.style.visibility = "hidden";
    showQuestion(myQuestions[0]);
}
function showQuestion(questionAndAnswers) {
    const shuffledAnswers = _.shuffle(questionAndAnswers.answers);
    questionTag.innerText = questionAndAnswers.question;
    shuffledAnswers.forEach(({ text, correct }, i) => {
        answerTag[i].innerText = text;
        answerTag[i].dataset.correct = correct;
    });
}
document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach((answer) => {
    answer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target.dataset) {
            answer.style.border = "1px solid black";
        }
    });
});
function nextQuestion() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.answer').forEach((answer) => {
        answer.style.border = 'none';
        setTimeout(function() {
            answer.style.border = ''
        })

    })
    const nextIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1;
    if (nextIndex <= myQuestions.length - 1) {
        showQuestion(myQuestions[nextIndex]);
        currentQuestionIndex = nextIndex;
    } else {
        end.style.visibility = "visible";
        nxt_question_btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
    <button id="start" type="button">Start quiz</button>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Quiz</h2>
        <div class="time">
            <span>Time left:</span>
            <p id="time"> 30</p>
        </div>
        <h3 id="question"></h3>
        <div class="answers">
            <button id="answer1" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer2" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer3" class="answer"></button>
            <button id="answer4" class="answer"></button>
        </div>
        <button id="next" class="btns">Next Question</button>
        <button id="end" class="btns">End Quiz</button>
    </div>
```